# "no matching Route53Zone found": Terraform's Route53 data source is not recognizing the hosted zone name

Tags: amazon-route53, terraform

Let's say that I have a public hosted zone names `example.com.`. I use the following piece of Terraform code to dynamically fetch the hosted zone id based on the name as per [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/route53_zone.html).

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = "example.com." # Notice the dot!!!
  private_zone = false
}
```

During `terraform plan` it comes up with this error:

```
Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* data.aws_route53_zone.main: no matching Route53Zone found
```

Is there a bug that I should report or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't actually need the dot, the data source will add it if it's not there. Can you check the zone using something like `aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name --query 'HostedZones[*].{Name:Name,PrivateZone:Config.PrivateZone}'` with the creds Terraform is using?

Comment: Also, although in the above example you aren't specifying a `vpc_id` parameter be aware that if you do then the data source implicitly assumes you want a private zone even if you set `private_zone = false`. I have recently raised a pull request to change this behaviour [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/11160)

Comment: ooh, all the infra I am trying to setup is inside a VPC! But the hosted zone is public. Does it create a conflict?

Comment: No, that's fine, it's only if you specify the `vpc_id` parameter in the data source. In your example that should work fine as long as the account has an `example.com` public zone and the account Terraform is working with has the ability to list hosted zones. I've been playing with this data source very recently and other than the issue my PR above sorts (with a use case in the PR if you're unsure as to why) it seems to work fine for this.

Comment: I checked with the aws cli and returns an empty list ( [ ] ).That means that the user does not have privileges?

Comment: Either that or you don't actually have the domain in that account. Assuming it is there then yes it sounds like a lack of privileges.

Comment: Your comments led me to the solution...I actually was trying to use as data source a hosted zone from another account having in mind that Route53 as a resource is global.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`aws_route53_zone` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/route53_zone.html) will list all the hosted zones in the account that Terraform has permissions to view.

If you are trying to reference a zone in another account then you can do this by creating a role/user in the account with the zone that has permissions to list all the zones (`route53:ListHostedZones*,route53:GetHostedZone*`) and then having a second "provider" be used for this data source.

So you might have something like this:

```
provider "aws" {
    # ... access keys etc/assume role block
}

# DNS account
provider "aws" {
    alias = "dns_zones"
    # ... access keys etc/assume role block
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  provider = "aws.dns_zones"
  name = "example.com." # Notice the dot!!!
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id}"
  name = "www.${data.aws_route53_zone.main.name}"
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have created a cross-account role with full access to R53 in the 1st account. I have tested it manually with a user from the second account (after adding the inline policy) and everything is ok. I can assume the role and manage R53. I also did the changes you posted. Do I need to add in any of the two provider blocks an assume_role parameter??

Comment: As long as that's working for you then that's okay. We tried that a while back but couldn't get Terraform correctly assuming cross account roles although that may have been down to use using the instance role to assume a cross account role.

Comment: This doesn't work, I cannot query public zone via name with private=false, only zone_id works...

Comment: Do you get an error? Is it because you have multiple private zones with the same name? If you're having issues you should consider asking a separate question showing what you've tried and what errors you're getting. If it's useful then link back to this question.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Oh duuuuuuuuuude it's 3:40am and I'm queueing Bette Middler because Did you ever know you're my hero... (if it weren't for the `Notice the dot!!!` comment................... it'd be 6:40am and I'd still be here)

Answer (score 5):

Using the `zone_id` instead of the `name` did it for me.

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "api2" {
  # name = "example.com."
  zone_id = "REPLACEWITHYOURID"
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, also, without the need of the `vpc_id`

Comment: This worked for me, also, without the need of the vpc_id

Answer (score 3):

Check if your zone name is private or false and delete the last dot in name. I had that problem of layer eight .

From:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = "example.com."
  private_zone = false
}
```

To:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = "example.com"
  private_zone = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to work when it is placed inside a module. Simply move it to the manifest where the module is called at the root level.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error "Error: no matching Route53Zone found" when using aws provider alias, our cause was the incorrect aws access id/key and once sorted worked fine, we didn't need the . for the record :)